# textarea must be written into when only a certain checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Im trying to work out how to code validation via javascript so that if only the other skills checkbox is clicked then the textarea can not be left empty

```
     label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="CSS" 
    checked="checked"/>CSS</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="HTML" 
     />HTML</label> 
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="JavaScript" 
     />JavaScript</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="management" 
   />management experience</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="PHP" 
    />PHP</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="other" />other 
     skills (please list bellow)</label>
      <br/><br/>
      <label>Other Skills:</label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="otherskills" placeholder="Enter 
        any other skills that would be usefull for the job..."></textarea>
```

Comment: Please add the code that you've tried, in order to do the validation.

Comment: @some hi yes  i did however actually did it in a bit of an easier way.. with some assistance .. thanks

Comment: @some of us a learning and have been told that we have specific requirements for tasks in javascript that we have no choice but to use alert...

Answer (score 0):

You can border red textarea like below

```
if(checkcount == 1 && checkedother == true && otherskill == ""){
           //console.log(otherskill == "")
           $("[name='otherskills'").css('border', '1px solid red');

       }else{
          $("[name='otherskills'").css('border', '');
       }
```

Check checkcount == 1 && checkedother == true && otherskill == ""

```
 function check(){
   //console.log($("[name='skill[]'").val());
   var checkedother = false;
   var otherskill = $("[name='otherskills'").val();
  $("[name='skill[]'").each(function () {
       var checked = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");


       if(checked == "other"){
           checkedother = true;
       }
  });

  if(checkedother == true && otherskill == ""){
           //console.log(otherskill == "")
           $("[name='otherskills'").css('border', '1px solid red');

       }else{
          $("[name='otherskills'").css('border', '');
       }

  return false;

}
```

```js
function check(){
   //console.log($("[name='skill[]'").val());
   var checkedother = false;
   var otherskill = $("[name='otherskills'").val();
   var checkcount = 0;
  $("[name='skill[]'").each(function () {
       var checked = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
       if(checked != "") checkcount++;
       
       if(checked == "other"){
           checkedother = true;
       }
  });
  
  if(checkcount == 1 && checkedother == true && otherskill == ""){
           //console.log(otherskill == "")
           $("[name='otherskills'").css('border', '1px solid red');
          
       }else{
          $("[name='otherskills'").css('border', '');
       }
  
  return false;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return check();"> 
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="CSS" 
    checked="checked"/>CSS</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="HTML" 
     />HTML</label> 
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="JavaScript" 
     />JavaScript</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="management" 
   />management experience</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="PHP" 
    />PHP</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="other" />other 
     skills (please list bellow)</label>
      <br/><br/>
      <label>Other Skills:</label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="otherskills" placeholder="Enter 
        any other skills that would be usefull for the job..."></textarea>
        
        <button>Send</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of `checked` inputs as well as your `textarea`.

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

let count = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    count = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length;
    if(count > 0 && textArea.value.length == 0) { 
        alert('Please enter some text');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Success');
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="CSS" 
    checked="checked"/>CSS</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="HTML" 
     />HTML</label> 
<label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="JavaScript" 
     />JavaScript</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="management" 
   />management experience</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="PHP" 
    />PHP</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="other" />other 
     skills (please list bellow)</label>
      <br/><br/>
<label>Other Skills:</label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="otherskills" placeholder="Enter 
        any other skills that would be usefull for the job..."></textarea>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class `.lastitem` to last checkbox  and call below function

```
$(":checkbox").click(countChecked);

function countChecked() {
                if ($(".lastitem > input").is(':checked')) {
                    $("#otherskills").show();
                    //document.getElementById("otherskills").disabled = false;
                }
                else {
                    $("#otherskills").hide();
                    //document.getElementById("otherskills").disabled = true;
                }
            }
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="CSS" 
    checked="checked"/>CSS</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="HTML" 
     />HTML</label> 
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="JavaScript" 
     />JavaScript</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="management" 
   />management experience</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="PHP" 
    />PHP</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="other" />other 
     skills (please list bellow)</label>
      <br/><br/>
      <label>Other Skills:</label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class=".lastitem" name="otherskills" placeholder="Enter 
        any other skills that would be usefull for the job..."></textarea>
```